# delete values from an array in an object using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, splice

What is wrong with my code? Why is the "deleteMessage(index)" function not removing any messages??

```
var facebookProfile = {
  messages: ["hi", "bye", "test"],
  deleteMessage: function deleteMessage(index) {
     facebookProfile.messages.splice(index);
  },
};
```

Comment: No? Your method should remove all messages starting from `index`. How are you calling the method?

Comment: How are you calling this code?

Comment: Splice doesn't modify the source array.  It returns a new array.  See the documentation

Comment: @Amy Ohh it does. Do you mean slice? Because OP has splice which does mutate the array.

Comment: @Amy [wrong](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice): _The `splice()` method changes the contents of an array by removing existing elements and/or adding new elements._

Comment: Yes I meant slice. I'm on my phone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to specify how many items you want to splice (1 I guess assuming the name is singular) Otherwise it would remove all the messages to the end starting the index.

```js
var facebookProfile = {
  messages: ["hi", "bye", "test"],
  deleteMessage: function deleteMessage(index) {
     facebookProfile.messages.splice(index, 1);
  },
}

facebookProfile.deleteMessage(1)
console.log(facebookProfile.messages)

facebookProfile.deleteMessage(1)
console.log(facebookProfile.messages)
```

Comment: Don't see anything wrong with this... well, one thing. Semantically, probably better to use `this.messages.splice(...)`. But this still works.